# Leaving guitar body without the neck

Tags: electric-guitar, guitar-neck

I have a guitar with a tremolo bridge (Ibanez GRG140 to be exact) and my question is if I remove the strings and neck leaving only the body will it degrade the state of the guitar (I intend to install the neck in about a month) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simple answer is no. There is nothing that will be damaged if you take the neck off for a while.

I have various guitars that live in this state between necks and the only thing that I need to do is sort the truss rod whenever I a set up a new neck, but that needs to be done with any new neck.